# wpf validation - how can I get this code to trigger a validation as typing occurs (cf when leaving the field)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

how can I get this code to trigger a validation as typing occurs (cf when leaving the field).  The code below works OK in terms of validation, however it does not work until leaving the field (not as you type).

XAML

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                <Setter 
                    Property="ToolTip" 
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

.
.
.

```
                <TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ProxyModeRadioButton, Path=IsChecked}"
                         Width="Auto" Name="ProxyHostTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="150" >
                    <TextBox.Text>
                        <Binding Path="Proxy" >
                            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                <local:SpecialCharactersRule/> 
                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                        </Binding>
                    </TextBox.Text>
                </TextBox>
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ProxyModeRadioButton, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path=IsChecked}" Width="Auto" Name="ProxyHostTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="150" >
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Proxy" >
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:SpecialCharactersRule/> 
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Note the **UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged** in the binding.

**UPDATE**

As blindmeis stated below, I put the UpdateSourceTrigger in the wrong Binding box.. my mistake.  It should go with the TextBox.Text.  Sorry about that...

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ProxyModeRadioButton, Path=IsChecked}" Width="Auto" Name="ProxyHostTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="150" >
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Proxy" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:SpecialCharactersRule/> 
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: umm, didn't seem to work?  I've now got the following binding line "IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ProxyModeRadioButton, Path=IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}", but still only works when I tab out of the textbox (i.e. doesn't trigger as I'm typing)

Comment: got it - put in the <TextBox> area as opposed to the <TextBox.Text> area  :)

Answer (score 2):

Dave is nearly right but i think you want your validation occur when your TEXT property change, so you have to add the **`UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to the TEXT binding**

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ProxyModeRadioButton, Path=IsChecked}"
         Width="Auto" Name="ProxyHostTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="150">
<TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="Proxy" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <local:SpecialCharactersRule/> 
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
</TextBox.Text>
```

Comment: umm, didn't seem to work?  I've now got the following binding line "IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ProxyModeRadioButton, Path=IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}", but still only works when I tab out of the textbox (i.e. doesn't trigger as I'm typing)

Comment: haha oops, you are right, I totally put it in the wrong spot.

Comment: @Greg try the binding i have posted. you still use the one from Dave :) you just have to take the the updatesourcetrigger away from the IsEnabled binding and put it to the TEXT binding.